# Why is it displaying my answer as being correct, if i select all the check boxes?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have four checkboxes along with a textview that displays a question. I am trying to create a simple multiple choice quiz with check boxes.I managed to display a toast to the user if they select the correct answer. and a toast if they select a wrong answer. The problem that i'm having is if the user selects all the answer it gets counted as being correct. Can someone help me with this. The result variables stores the check boxes result as a string and i'm comparing it to the correct answer.

```
            if(result1 == firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer() && result2 == firstQuestion.getSecondCorrectAnswer()){
                    currentScore = currentScore + 1 + userScore;
                    Intent i = new Intent(CheckBoxQuestions.this, ResultScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("finalScore",currentScore);
                    startActivity(i);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(CheckBoxQuestions.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    currentScore = currentScore + 0 + userScore;
                    Intent i = new Intent(CheckBoxQuestions.this, ResultScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("finalScore",currentScore);
                    startActivity(i);

                }




        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I would use a `radio button array` for that (only **one** selection allowed). *Otherwise* you have to manage the `radio functionality` yourself.

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: is result1 a string? Then use .equals(). == compares references. If .equals not overridden it does ==. However in String Class .equals is overridden allowing it to compare Strings as intended.

Comment: One elegant solution would be to use a button group to allow only one selection if that is possible in the context of your problem. If the user should be able to select different solutions (there may be several answers that are correct), then you should probably invert the test. That is test that the user didn't answer incorrectly. If the user should select all the right solution and only those, you should test that all correct answers are checked and no incorrect answer is cecked.

Comment: please post full code

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the result which is a string with `==`. The `==` operation compares references of two objects (or values for a primitive). Since Strings are objects, `==` is not recommended for comparison of the characters. Use the `.equals()` method instead. `<String>.equals(<other String>)` The `.equals()` method as defined in `Object` is the same as `==`. However, many objects such as Strings override `.equals()` In the case of Strings, to compare character by character.

Comment: I may have misread the question but it does appear that he/she is comparing strings, since he/she said that the code works if the user answers correctly... It may be integers or enumerations...

Comment: @ebigeon yeah op says results are stored as Strings so... it is strange why == works for 2 strings that are new strings not in the string pool not referencing each other. More code needs to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RadioGroup and RadioButton as mentioned below, it will allow you to select only one radio button, that is only one answer. Radio buttons will be in single radio group.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Radio Button 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio Button 2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio Button 3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radio Button 4"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

One elegant solution would be to use a button group to allow only one selection if that is possible in the context of your problem. If the user should be able to select different solutions (there may be several answers that are correct), then you should probably invert the test. That is test that the user didn't answer incorrectly.

To show the latter with code:

```
if(isCorrectAnswers(firstQuestion) && !hasIncorrectAnswer(firstQuestion)) {
    ... // React for correct answer
} else {
    ... // React for incorrect answer
}
```

with

```
private boolean isCorrectAnswers(AnswerSelectionChoice choice) {
    return choice.isSelectedCorrectChoice() && isSelectedSecondCorrectChoice() && ...;
}
```

and

```
private boolean hasIncorrectAnswer(AnswerSelectionChoice choice) {
    return choice.isSelectedIncorrectChoice() || isSelectedSecondIncorrectChoice() || ...;
}
```